# Cannot read property 'success' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following javascript function

```
$("#formLogin").submit(function(e){     
       e.preventDefault();

        var memberUserName = $(this).find("#memberUserName").val();
        var memberOldPassword = $(this).find("#memberOldPassword").val();
        alert(memberUserName);
        alert(memberOldPassword);
        var obj = {memberUserName: memberUserName, memberOldPassword: memberOldPassword};
        var url = $(this).attr("action");
        $.post(url, obj, function(r){

            if(r.success) window.location.replace('http://www.example.org/memberAccount/memberDashboard');

            else  $('#errorMessageTop').fadeIn();

        }, 'json')
   })
```

When I alert, memberOldPassword i get undefined. In my form, i have the filed, here is the code:

```
<input type="password" class="good_input" id="memberOldPassword" name="memberOldPassword" style="float:right;width:135px;"/><br />
```

Here is the PHP code of my controller:

```
 public function loginCheck()
    {     
        // set the validation rules
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('memberUserName', 'Username', 'required|trim|encode_php_tags');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('memberOldPassword', 'Password', 'required|trim|encode_php_tags');
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<br /><p class=jsdiserr>', '</p><br />');
        // if validation is passed

        if ($this->form_validation->run() != FALSE) 
        {


            $this->db->where('memberUserName', $this->input->post('memberUserName'));
            $this->db->where('memberOldPassword', strtoupper(md5("EBOSS/".$this->input->post('memberOldPassword')."/EBOSS")));
            $query = $this->membersModel->get();
            if($query)
            {

                $data = array(
                    'memberID'                      => $query[0]['memberID'],
                    'memberUserName'                => $query[0]['memberUserName'],
                    'memberOldPassword'             => $query[0]['memberOldPassword'],
                    'memberEmail'                   => $query[0]['memberEmail'],
                    'isUserLoggedIn' => TRUE
                );           
                $members = $query->result_array();            
                $this->session->set_userdata('currentMember',$data);

                echo json_encode(array("success" => true));
        } else {   
                echo json_encode(array("success" => false, "error" => "Wrong credentials"));
        }
        //  form validation has failed 
        } else {     
            $errorMessage = "Wrong Username or passwrod!";
        }
    }   // end of function loginCheck
```

I use jQuery v1.7.2, and PHP version is 5.39

Anyone has an idea why do I get undefined when I alter the password?

Comment: if i alert it i get undefined in the popup

Comment: Are you on Chrome? What happens if you try `$("#memberOldPassword").val();` in the console after the page has been rendered?

Comment: @user2417624 what u r getting in $(this).find("#memberOldPassword") alone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(this) doesn't refer to the form apparently, since you're using id's you might also do this

```
var memberOldPassword = $("#memberOldPassword").val();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mkhftwqv/

Comment: @user2417624 Next time post all relevant HTML markup in question, as the FORM one

Comment: That will do the trick, but you're not making your code more maintainable this way: instead of looking for an input within your form you're looking for it everywhere...

Comment: @JanChimiak But as IDs must be unique, what's wrong?

Comment: You could use in stead var memberOldPassword = $("#formLogin").find("#memberOldPassword").val();

Comment: @A.Wolff They **should** be unique - as in _in ideal world_. If for some obscure reason the poster gets two #memberOldPassword elements then val() will return the value of the _first_ one, and the poster will spend the rest of his day on debugging this.

Comment: @JanChimiak if you duplicate IDs, you deserve what you get. That's not a good reason not to use ID as a direct selector.

Answer (score 1):

Check your HTML. Is the password really inside the form tag? What does the find("#memberOldPassword") really return? Console it out!

Test JavaScript:

```
$("#formLogin").submit(function(e){     
    e.preventDefault();
    var memberOldPassword = $(this).find("#memberOldPassword").val();
    alert(memberOldPassword);
})
```

Correct HTML (alerts entered value):

```
<form id="formLogin">
    <input type="password" class="good_input" id="memberOldPassword" name="memberOldPassword" style="float:right;width:135px;"/><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Wrong HTML (alerts undefined):

```
<form id="formLogin" >
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
<input type="password" class="good_input" id="memberOldPassword" name="memberOldPassword" style="float:right;width:135px;"/><br />
```

Comment: This is likely the right line of investigation.  The OP should just do some debugging by examining intermediate results to see exactly what is causing the password to come back empty.  Basic debugging really.

Comment: I remove the link to the script and I add your first snippet where the form is. same result, i get undefined again. checking the rest of your sugesstions now.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to post an example of your server response. Assuming that it is valid JSON, it must contain a success property like this:

```
{
    success: ...
}
```

Otherwise it will be undefined.

Looking at your code however, this is probably what you're looking for:

```
$.post(url, obj).done(function(r) {
    window.location.replace('http://www.example.org/memberAccount/memberDashboard');
}).fail(function(r) {
    $('#errorMessageTop').fadeIn();
});
```

The [`.done()`](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/) and [`.fail()`](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.fail/) functions are designed to handle the specific cases of success and failure. If you need to work with the server response, you can do so in the callback functions where the response is passed in as `r`.

Comment: I think this question is really about why `memberOldPassword` is empty before the Ajax call.

Comment: @jfriend00 title and question do not agree.

Comment: I think the title is the symptom, not the actual issue (poorly selected as the title), but the OP clearly describes and talks about the problem of `memberOldPassword` being empty which would likely lead to an error or empty result from the Ajax call since it would not match the new password.  Certainly, the OP can weigh in here to clarify.

Comment: Afeter using the above code, i still get undefined, and same error message in the console. I am editing my quesiton now, and I will post the php code...

Comment: @user2417624 That's a wrong debugging diagnostic to check at server side if you have already issue with DOM element client side